# How to unset CSS text-shadow using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

I use JavaScript to set the CSS `text-shadow` property. Here is my code to set the `text-shadow` property:

```
var text = document.getElementById("text");
text.style.textShadow = "1px 1px 0 red";
```

Once I set it, how do I unset the CSS `text-shadow` property using JavaScript? I tried

```
text.style.textShadow = "0 0 0 0";
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 4):

```
text.style.textShadow = "none";
```

Or, depending on your needs:

```
text.style.textShadow = "inherit";
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
text.style.textShadow = "none";
```

In fact, playing around with this, setting it to `"0 0"`, `null`, and `""` all seem to work as well.

See working test: http://jsfiddle.net/YwPF9/

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
text.style.textShadow = "0 0";
```

Comment: I'm using FireFox 8, using that code to unset, my text still looking bolder. That is not the same before applying the text-shadow property